# Regular rings with F-finite field of fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra, positive-characteristic, regular-rings

Let $S$ be a regular domain of characteristic $p>0$ with fraction field $K$. Assume that $K$ is $F$-finite, meaning that $K$ is a finite module over $K^p$. Does it follow that $S$ is also $F$-finite?

Diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is false. [[Datta–Smith](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/ant.2016.10.1057), Ex. 4.5.1] give an example of a DVR that is not $F$-finite, whose fraction field is $\mathbf{F}_p(x,y)$.

A way to produce more examples is the following:

**Proposition** [[Datta–Smith](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/ant.2016.10.1057), Prop. 2.6.1]**.** *A noetherian domain of positive characteristic is $F$-finite if and only if it is excellent and its fraction field is $F$-finite.*

Thus, any non-excellent regular domain of positive characteristic with $F$-finite fraction field is a counterexample to your claim.

There are many examples of non-excellent regular domains in the literature: see [[Nagata](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=460307), (E3.3)], [[Matsumura](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=575344), (34.B)], and [[Raynaud](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/orgogozo/travaux_de_Gabber/GTG/GTG.pdf), Exp. I, §11] for more examples. It was not clear to me, however, which of those existing examples have $F$-finite function field. On the other hand, combining Prop. 11.6 in Raynaud with Datta–Smith's proposition above gives a systematic way to construct non-excellent DVR's with $F$-finite fraction field.

**Edit.** Datta–Smith recent posted [another preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03628), which discusses these questions in more detail. See §1.2 and §3 in particular.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! Isn't it true that, if  $A$ is regular and $K=K^p$, then $A=A^p$ (even if $A$ is not excellent) ? I thought about showing $A_{\mathfrak{p}}=A_{\mathfrak{p}}^p$ for any localization of $A$, which should be true because $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a factorial ring (but maybe the article you linked is going to prove me wrong).

Comment: @Yoël I am confused by your question (what is a regular domain with $K = K^p$, other than a field?), but here is a stronger statement: if $A$ is normal and $K = K^p$, then $A = A^p$. Let $a \in A$, which is an element of $K$ that is integral over $A^p$. But $K = K^p$ and the fact that $A^p$ is normal implies $a \in A^p$ as well, hence $A = A^p$.

Comment: Can you please explain why (or give some references) we have $A=K$ if $A$ is a regular, integral domain with $K=K^p$ ? It looks like a stupid question but I'm lacking some basics about regular rings :-)

Comment: @Yoël Suppose $A$ is a normal domain with $K = K^p$. The previous comment shows $A = A^p$. If $A$ is not a field, it has a nonzero maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. We claim $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}^2$. Let $f \in \mathfrak{m}$. Since $A = A^p$, we have $f = g^p$ for some $g \in A$. But $\mathfrak{m}$ is radical, hence $g \in \mathfrak{m}$. Thus, $f = g^p \in \mathfrak{m}^p \subseteq \mathfrak{m}^2$. Now recall that a regular ring is noetherian, but noetherian rings can never satisfy $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}^2$ by using Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: I had forgotten that any regular domain is normal. Thanks ;)

Comment: @TakumiMurayama's remark shows more generally that if $A$ is a Noetherian domain whose fraction field $K$ is perfect of char p > 0, then $A = K$. There is probably a simple argument for this, but here is what I can think of now: Let $\tilde{A}$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $K$. Then by the above, $\tilde{A}$ is perfect. Note, $\tilde{A}$ is the intersection of all DVRs of $K$ containing $A$. But a perfect field of char p cannot have DVRs (not counting $K$ as one). So $\tilde{A} = K$. Now show that $A \hookrightarrow K$ can never be integral unless $A = K$ (a general fact).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the result must be true though I don't have the answer right now, but maybe this can help (or not):

Denote $\phi: A\rightarrow A$, $x\mapsto x^p$ the Frobenius morphism, and still denote $\phi: K\rightarrow K$ its extension to $K$.

Let $n\ge 1$ be an integer and assume $\mathcal{B}=\{f_1, ..., f_n\}$ is a $\phi(K)$-basis of $K$.
We can always assume that $f_1$, ..., $f_n$ belong to $A$ (if $f_i=\frac{a_i}{b_i}$, $a_i$, $b_i\in A$, then $\{b_1^{p-1}a_1, ..., b_n^{p-1}a_n\}$ is still a $\phi(K)$-basis of $K$).

Identify $K$ to $\phi(K)^n$ through $\mathcal{B}$, and denote $M\subset A$ the $\phi(A)$-module (free) of rank $n$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$. Then $A/M$ is a torsion module over $\phi(A)$, by assumption.
Now I think we have to look for properties about torsion modules over regular domains (maybe first assume that $R$ is local ?), which I don't know much (but I'll look at it).

Hope this helped a bit.